# Xcode automatically updates Package.resolved

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I have an Xcode project that has this private package dependency:
[image]

This Framework packages has in its Package.swift file this dependency:

```
.package(url: "https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit.git", .upToNextMajor(from: "3.3.0")),
```

The part of the Package.resolved referring to this PhoneNumberKit looks like this:

```
{
   "identity" : "phonenumberkit",
   "kind" : "remoteSourceControl",
   "location" : "https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit.git",
   "state" : {
     "revision" : "6edd6e38a30aec087cb97f7377edf876c29a427e",
     "version" : "3.5.9"
   }
}
```

However, when I open Xcode, it automatically does a "Resolving Package Graph" step, which modifies the Package.resolved to this:

```
{
   "identity" : "phonenumberkit",
   "kind" : "remoteSourceControl",
   "location" : "https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit.git",
   "state" : {
     "revision" : "56f612ea0178406b1ff57846401bd68a57d96a80",
     "version" : "3.5.4"
   }
}
```

To me this doesn't make sense at all, the point of having a Package.resolved file should be to ensure all developers working on the same project use the same version for all the dependencies.

Why is Xcode automatically modifying the version of this dependency?

*Note: I have put here this PhoneNumberKit package as example, but this actually happens to me with other packages as well*

Comment: No, it doesn't work like other package manager lock files. `Package.resolved` merely documents the resolution, it doesn't control it. If you build with `xcodebuild` there's a command line option to stop this behaviour `-disableAutomaticPackageResolution`. So there might be some equivalent  in Xcode, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: I meet the same problem. Xcode auto update the version of SPMs library event the version is static defined.

Comment: I had the same problem (I work on a big corporate project). I stopped opening the `xcodeproj` and started using the `xcworkspace`, which fixed the issue for me.